# Python Django: model <name> not recognized in views.py

Tags: python, django

**Background:**
I want to open the CourseForm in order to edit existing course data by clicking on a link.

**Problem description:**
Running the development server, if I click on the link, I get the following error:

```
  File "/home/usr/project/workbench/courses/views.py", line 92, in ManageCourseView
course = Course.objects.filter(id=id)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'Course' referenced before assignment
```

Line 92 in ManageCourseView:

```
from django.views import generic
from .models import Course
from .forms import CourseForm
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
    
def ManageCourseView(request, id):
course = Course.objects.get(id=id)

if request.method == 'POST':
    form = CourseForm(request.POST, instance=course)
    if form.is_valid():
        # create a new `Course` and save it to the db
        Course = form.save()
        # calculate additional data
        start_date = datetime.strptime((form['start_date'].value()), '%d.%m.%Y')
        end_date = datetime.strptime((form['end_date'].value()), '%d.%m.%Y')
        max_delivery_date = (end_date + timedelta(weeks=4))
        month = datetime.strftime(start_date, '%B')
        month_int = datetime.strftime(start_date, '%m')
        weekday = datetime.strftime(start_date, '%A')
        year = datetime.strftime(start_date, '%Y')

        if (end_date-start_date).days == 1:
            gvk_type = 'Wochenendkurs'
            gvk_type_id = 'WK'
        else:
            gvk_type = 'Abendkurs'
            gvk_type_id = 'AK'
        
        courseName = 'Geburtsvorbereitungskurs {} {} - {}'.format(month, year, gvk_type)

        if gvk_type_id == 'WK':
            start_time = datetime.strptime('09:30', '%H:%M')
            end_time = datetime.strptime('16:00', '%H:%M')
        else:
            start_time = datetime.strptime('18:30', '%H:%M')
            end_time = datetime.strptime('20.30', '%H:%M')
        # save to database
        Course.name = courseName
        Course.start_time = start_time
        Course.end_time = end_time
        Course.price = 400
        Course.max_delivery_date = max_delivery_date
        Course.save()
        # redirect to the detail page of the course we just created
        # we can provide the url pattern arguments as arguments to redirect function
        return redirect('courses:detail', Course.id)
else:
    form = CourseForm(instance=course)

return render(request,
            'courses/manage_course.html',
            {'form': form})
```

Definition of the Course model:

```
class Course(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField('Kurs', max_length=200)
        capacity = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField('Anzahl Plätze')
        start_date = models.DateField('Erster Kurstag')
        end_date = models.DateField('Letzer Kurstag')
        price = models.FloatField('Preis', null=True, blank=True)
    
        def __str__(self):
            return self.name
```

I am referencing the Course model in other view functions and there it works perfectly fine.

Definition of the CourseForm:

```
class CourseForm(forms.ModelForm):

        class Meta:
            model = Course
            exclude = ['name', 'price']
```

Extract of the html with the respective link:

```html
<div class="column is-two-thirds">
    <a href="{% url 'courses:manage_course' course.id %}">
      <div class="box has-background-info is-clickable">
        <p class="title has-text-white">{{ course.name }}</p>
        <p class="has-text-white">{{ course.start_date }} - {{ course.end_date }}</p>
        <p class="has-text-white">{{ course.start_time }} - {{ course.end_time }}</p>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
```

**Question:**
Why is "Course" interpreted as local variable (which is obviously not defined) and not as the Course model/class?

Comment: You probably assign to the name `Course` somewhere in the non-shared section of the `ManageCourseView` function. Can you share the full function?

Comment: Updated the ManageCourseView. You're right, I do reference Course in the view

Comment: You should name the variable in the view something other than `Course`, this local variable clashes with the imported model name - `obj = form.save()`

Comment: Thank you Iain! Solved this issue